# group by in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I am running following LINQ query in order to group by `CategoryID`

```
var test = from x in ent.Products  
           group x by x.CategoryID into g
           select new  
           {
               x.EntityKey
           };
```

But I am getting following error:

> The name 'x' does not exist in the current context

Any idea why?

Comment: what do you want to extract from query???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find method syntax easier to follow:

If you want `test` to be a list of CategoryIds that your products belong to then try:

```
var test = ent.Products.GroupBy(p => p.CategoryId)
                       .Select(g => g.Key)
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because after `group` statement `x` is no longer available. You can only use `g` there.

Answer (score 1):

You have to:

```
...
from something in g
select new {
  something.EntityKey
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you group by a set of data into a group, the variable you use to query the data(in your case it is `x`) becomes unavailable for the `select` statement.

After grouping, what you can do is to use the group(in your case it is `g`), you can reach `g.Key` or query `g` with `from` and reach inside it in the `select` statement like below:

```
var test = from x in ent.Products  
           group x by x.CategoryID into g
           from b in g
           select b.EntityKey;
```

This is possible though I can not say it is the best practice.(not that I am saying it is bad, it is just I rarely saw LINQ queries like that.I have done it myself a couple of times.)